# Grep for exact match when there is no more words

Tags: linux, bash

I have two strings like below:

`Word`

`More than one word`

How to use grep to match only with the first one?
I would like to have results when there is no more characters around the word I'm searching for.
When there is a string like the second one, it should find nothing.

Is it possible to achieve with grep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this expression

```
grep -i ^word$ file
```

**Explanation:**

Find all lines starting with (**^**) at the end of the line (**$**).
The **-i** flag makes the match insensitive, remove it if you want a case sensitive match

Answer (score 3):

The `-x` option says the regex needs to match the entire line.

```
grep -x 'Word' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Match the entire line:

```
grep -E '^Word$'
```

or

```
grep -P '^Word$'
```

Use `-i` to make it case insensitive, `-w` to only match entire words only.